# Square pattern in google maps circles

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, webbrowser-control, geometry

I'm working on a .Net application which has a Google map in it. It is simply done by using the .Net WebBrowser component showing a web page.

It works really good except for one thing: 
When I draw circles they have an ugly looking square pattern. At first I just noticed lines, vertical or horisontal but when doing editable circles and made them large enough, a square pattern appers. I does not matter which zoom factor I use, it is always the same amount of pixels between the lines.

If I show the exact same web page in a standard web browser (IE, Chrome or FF) it looks fine so it seems to have something to do with the WebBrowser component. But isn't that using the installed IE version?

Any help will be appreciated!

A picture says more than a thousand words but since I'm a new user at stackoverflow I'm not allowed to post the screenshot....

Best regards,
Mattias

Comment: You could upload the picture to imgur and then add a link. Someone will then edit your link to add the picture to the post.

Comment: You could you post an example on jsfiddle. `WebBrowser` control by default renders pages in IE7 Standards mode.